# Лимит на выбор файлов в input file multiple

Tags: html, post, файлы, input

Добре! Такой вопрос - есть поле

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" class="inpfile" multiple>
```

можно ли как то указать что пользователь может выбрать в него только 5 картинок- что бы больше он не мог? может есть какой то дополнительный атрибут? ибо не очень хочется нагружать сие дело ДЖаваскриптом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Простая функция на jquery

```
$filesCount = $("input[type='file']").get(0).files.length;
```

Comment: спасибо) я тоже сомневался что есть такой атрибут гугл ничего конкретного не дал